# MS Word files manipulation in ColdFusion 10/11

Tags: ms-word, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-11

I am working on a small project where I have to read more than 100 MS Word files and loop through each file and update their headers and footers. I want to accomplish this task in ColdFusion 10/11.

Is there any way I can get this done in ColdFusion?

Comment: What was your google search string?

Comment: What have you already tried? Which version of Word? If you're dealing with `.docx` files those are just XML and you should be able to manipulate them fairly easily.

Comment: on google I found, this can be done using COM .Net integration with CF. And call that class using <cfobject> . However, it seems like a lot of work and I don't have knowledge of .NET.

Comment: @3524344 They are ZIPs of multiple XML files. I suppose one unzip the file, change the data file via CF XML functions and re-zip the files. I would be concerned that some issue would get introduced that would make them un readable.

Comment: Aspose.com makes a number of products for helping with interacting with MS files.  I have only used their Java based products for interacting with Excel files via making the calls to those libraries through CF code.  They even have a link for showing how to create Word headers/footers via Java:  http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsjava/How+to++Create+Headers+Footers+using+DocumentBuilder  Might be a good starting point to work towards a proof of concept with.

Comment: You are welcome. Guess I should made it an answer instead of a comment ;) If you have trouble getting their classes to load then search their forums. Pretty sure I posted there how I got them to load for a couple different versions of CF

Comment: @Snipe656 - You can still do that. It would certainly be helpful to have an example of using Aspose from CF in the archives. @ Ronnie777 - For the benefit of others, could you elaborate on exactly how you used the tool in selected answer to manipulate the headers/footers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RIA Forge has a tool called

http://docxextractor.riaforge.org/

Which pulls data from docx files. It does not create docx files however

**Disclaimer:** I wrote this

Answer (score 0):

The `<cfdirectory>` tag can be used to work with files in a directory, for example getting a list to process using `<cfloop>`.

ColdFusion does have some support for MS Office files.  What you're trying to do can be done for an Excel spreadsheet, reading the file with `<cfspreadsheet>` and then using functions such as SpreadsheetSetFooter(), before writing the file.

However, there are no comparable functions for Word files!

[Adobe ColdFusion documentation](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Home)